# nulls_last() in sqlalchemy is expanding the labelled column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the following snippet I am creating a labelled expression and then using that expression inside of the `order_by` clause and the `select` clause. Normal `order_by` is working with the label but when I use the `nulls_last()` method, it is expanding the label again instead of using the previously provided column name.

```py
priceSum = func.sum(Book.price).label("price_sum")

# makes use of the labelled 'price_sum' column
print(select(Book.author, priceSum).group_by(Book.author).order_by(priceSum))

# but this expands the priceSum expression instead of using 'price_sum' label
print(select(Book.author, priceSum).group_by(Book.author).order_by(priceSum.nulls_last()))
```

Following are the SQL queries generated by the above snippet:

```sql
-- without nulls_last()
SELECT books.author, sum(books.price) AS price_sum 
FROM books GROUP BY books.author ORDER BY price_sum

-- with nulls_last()
SELECT books.author, sum(books.price) AS price_sum 
FROM books GROUP BY books.author ORDER BY sum(books.price) NULLS LAST
```

Reproducible Code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    Float,
    func,
    nulls_last,
    select,
    text,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base

# Create the engine to connect to the database
engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

# Create a Base class that will be the base for our declarative class mappings.
Base = declarative_base()


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    author = Column(String)
    price = Column(Float)


# This will create the table 'books' in the database if it doesn't exist.
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create a session to interact with the database
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Add some data to the table
book1 = Book(title="Book 1", author="Author 1", price=29.99)
book2 = Book(title="Book 2", author="Author 2", price=19.99)
book3 = Book(title="Book 3", author="Author 1", price=24.99)

# Add the books to the session and commit the changes to the database
session.add_all([book1, book2, book3])
session.commit()

priceSum = func.sum(Book.price).label("price_sum")
print("\n-- Without nulls_last(): \n")
print(select(Book.author, priceSum).group_by(Book.author).order_by(priceSum), "\n")
print("\n-- With nulls_last(): \n")
print(
    select(Book.author, priceSum).group_by(Book.author).order_by(priceSum.nulls_last()),
    "\n",
)
print("\n-- Using text() solves the issue: ")
print(
    select(Book.author, priceSum)
    .group_by(Book.author)
    .order_by(nulls_last(text("price_sum"))),
    "\n",
)
```

**NOTE**: I am using `order_by(nulls_last(text('price_sum')))` to overcome this for now,so I am looking for some other ways to solve this

Comment: Why do you care about whether a label or the expression it's referring to is used in a *generated* SQL query? The query generated by SQLAlchemy is meant not to be read or maintained by a human. A label is just an alias of an expression. It makes absolutely no difference to the database both space and performance-wise whether an expression or a label of it is used in a query.

Comment: @blhsing It's not that I am doing anything with the SQL query, I just wanted to know if there is any way to do this and does the calculation happen only once when we have it in both select clause and order by clause in every situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have any labelled columns in the `SELECT` clause that we want to use in other places, then [SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#ordering-or-grouping-by-a-label) suggests to use the label name directly inside of `order_by` or `group_by`, without using any `text`, if a column with that label doesn't exist then it'll raise an error, otherwise it will simply make use of the provided label name.

Following snippet makes use of this:

```py
priceSum = func.sum(Book.price).label("price_sum")
print(
    select(Book.author, priceSum)
    .group_by(Book.author)
    .order_by(nulls_last(desc("price_sum")))
)
```

and we get the following SQL query which makes use of the label `price_sum` instead of recreating the `sum` calculation:

```
SELECT books.author, sum(books.price) AS price_sum 
FROM books GROUP BY books.author ORDER BY price_sum DESC NULLS LAST
```

**Reproducible Code:**

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    Float,
    func,
    nulls_last,
    select,
    text,
    desc,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base

# Create the engine to connect to the database
engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

# Create a Base class that will be the base for our declarative class mappings.
Base = declarative_base()


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    author = Column(String)
    price = Column(Float)


# This will create the table 'books' in the database if it doesn't exist.
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create a session to interact with the database
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Add some data to the table
book1 = Book(title="Book 1", author="Author 1", price=29.99)
book2 = Book(title="Book 2", author="Author 2", price=19.99)
book3 = Book(title="Book 3", author="Author 1", price=24.99)

# Add the books to the session and commit the changes to the database
session.add_all([book1, book2, book3])
session.commit()

priceSum = func.sum(Book.price).label("price_sum")
print("\n-- Without nulls_last(): \n")
print(select(Book.author, priceSum).group_by(Book.author).order_by(priceSum), "\n")
print("\n-- With nulls_last(): \n")
print(
    select(Book.author, priceSum).group_by(Book.author).order_by(priceSum.nulls_last()),
    "\n",
)
print("\n-- Using text() solves the issue: ")
print(
    select(Book.author, priceSum)
    .group_by(Book.author)
    .order_by(nulls_last(text("price_sum"))),
    "\n",
)

print("\n-- Providing the label name as suggested in SQLAlchemy Docs: ")
print(
    select(Book.author, priceSum)
    .group_by(Book.author)
    .order_by(nulls_last(desc("price_sum")))
)
```